# Form submission validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve: Looks like my if statement is wrong for the input text field.

1. There are 2 parent divs with class (**parent** and graph-radio)
2. In **parent** div, 2 sub-parents. 1 with radio and 1 with input text.
3. I should select any one of the radio buttons only, I can't select both the div's radio buttons.
4. If they select radio button from first parent div then it is mandatory to type in at-least in any one of the input text boxes.
5. If they have selected the second parent radio box, then the submit button along with last input text box should be clickable/editable.
6. If they have selected first parent radio button along with any text typed in any one of the text field then again the submit button along with last input text box should be clickable/editable.
7. If nothing is selected then the last input text with submit button should remain inactive

```js
var init_txt = $(".init-one-text");
var init_radio_btn = document.querySelector('input[name="radios-init"]:checked') != null ? document.querySelector('input[name="radios-init"]:checked').value : "";
var graph_radio_btn = document.querySelector('input[name="graph-init"]:checked') != null ? document.querySelector('input[name="graph-init"]:checked').value : "";

if ((init_radio_btn != '' && init_txt.length > 1) || graph_radio_btn != '') {

  $('.add-to-bag-section input[type=text], .add-to-bag-section input[type=submit]').attr('readonly', false);
  $('.add-to-bag-section input[type=text], .add-to-bag-section input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);

} else {
  $('.add-to-bag-section input[type=text], .add-to-bag-section input[type=submit]').attr('readonly', true);
  $('.add-to-bag-section input[type=text], .add-to-bag-section input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">

  <!--Parent 1 Radio start-->
  <div class="init-radio-parent">
    <input type="radio" name="radios-init">
    <label for="radios-init">One</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radios-init">
    <label for="radios-init">two</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radios-init">
    <label for="radios-init">three</label>
  </div>
  <!--Parent 1 Radio end-->

  <!--Parent 1 text input start-->
  <div class="text-field-init">
    <input type="text" id="init-one-id" class="init-one-text" name="init-one-text" maxlength="1/">
    <input type="text" id="init-two-id" class="init-one-text" name="init-one-text" maxlength="1/">
    <input type="text" id="init-three-id" class="init-one-text" name="init-one-text" maxlength="1/">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <!--Parent 1 text input end-->

</div>

<br><br>

<!--Parent 2 text radio start-->
<div class="graph-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="graph-init">
  <label for="graph-init">GOne</label>
  <input type="radio" name="graph-init">
  <label for="graph-init">GTwo</label>
</div>
<!--Parent 2 text radio end-->

<br><br>

<div class="add-to-bag-section">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: _“I am trying to achieve: […]”_ - please go read [ask]. You are supposed to tell us what specifically you are having problems with, _not_ just drop your list of requirements here.

Comment: I am having issue with 1 line of code in the if statement. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: I am trying to explain what I am trying to achieve, so that understanding my code will be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the following code. Hope it will help you

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".graph-radio-btn").click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked")==true){
        $(".add_to_bag_input,.btn").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(".graph-radio-input").removeAttr("checked");
        }else{
        $(".add_to_bag_input,.btn").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }

        });
        $(".graph-radio-input").click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked")==true){
        $(".add_to_bag_input,.btn").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(".graph-radio-btn").removeAttr("checked");
        }else{
        $(".add_to_bag_input,.btn").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
        });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="parent">

          <!--Parent 1 Radio start-->
          <div class="init-radio-parent">
            <input type="radio" name="radios-init" class="graph-radio-btn">
            <label for="radios-init">One</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radios-init" class="graph-radio-btn">
            <label for="radios-init">two</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radios-init" class="graph-radio-btn">
            <label for="radios-init">three</label>
          </div>
          <!--Parent 1 Radio end-->

          <!--Parent 1 text input start-->
          <div class="text-field-init">
            <input type="text" id="init-one-id" class="init-one-text" name="init-one-text" maxlength="1/">
            <input type="text" id="init-two-id" class="init-one-text" name="init-one-text" maxlength="1/">
            <input type="text" id="init-three-id" class="init-one-text" name="init-one-text" maxlength="1/">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <!--Parent 1 text input end-->

        </div>

        <br><br>

        <!--Parent 2 text radio start-->
        <div class="graph-radio">
          <input type="radio" name="graph-init" class="graph-radio-input">
          <label for="graph-init">GOne</label>
          <input type="radio" name="graph-init" class="graph-radio-input">
          <label for="graph-init">GTwo</label>
        </div>
        <!--Parent 2 text radio end-->

        <br><br>

        <div class="add-to-bag-section">
          <input type="text" class="add_to_bag_input" disabled>
          <input type="submit" class="btn" disabled>
        </div>
```

```
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: It is a very good habit to explain what changes you made and why, so we all can see at a glance what you did and hopefully also understand why.

Answer (score 2):

I feel you should validate it yourself.

Write a separate function to enable the button like

```
 function enableSubmit() {
      $('#submitbutton').prop('disabled',false)
}
```

and then read the onchange values and make your logic like

```
$(document).onchange(function(){ 
var radio1=$('#radio1_id');
var radio2=$('#radio2_id');
var text1=$('#text1_id');
var text2=$('#text2_id');
  if(radio1 && !radio2){
         if(text1!=''){
              enableSubmit();
         }else{
              disableSubmit();
         }
  } 
  else if(radio2 && !radio1){
             disableSubmit();
  } 
});
```

u can use nested if to apply all your conditons